# How can I configure Moq to return new instance per call?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am trying to write a simple test with moq.
When calling the mocked method for the second time, after changing the return value from the first call, the moq framework returns the modified object. I guess this is because I am changing the same reference.

How can I ensure that each call to the moq will return the same value?

```
public class VersionData
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Str { get; set; }
}

public interface ILogic
{
    VersionData GetVersion();
}

[TestClass]
public class LogicTester
{
    private Mock<ILogic> _mock;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void InitSingleTest()
    {
        _mock = new Mock<ILogic>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        _mock.Setup(x => x.GetVersion()).Returns(new VersionData { Number = 1, Str = "1" });

        VersionData l1 = _mock.Object.GetVersion(); // OK
        l1.Number = 2;
        l1.Str = "2";


        // Not OK - I'd expect l2.Number = 1 and l2.Str = "1" but l2.Number = 2 and l2.Str = "2"
        VersionData l2 = _mock.Object.GetVersion(); 

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is confusingly worded.

> How can I ensure that each call to the moq will return the same value?

It suggests that you need the same value, instead, it should be "How can I configure Moq to return new instance per call?".

For that you have to use another overload of `Returns` method which takes a `Func<T>` as a parameter and pass a lambda. Your code as written configures the Moq to return the same instance for all calls made to `GetVersion` method.

So your Test method becomes

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    _mock.Setup(x => x.GetVersion())
         .Returns(() => new VersionData { Number = 1, Str = "1" });

    VersionData l1 = _mock.Object.GetVersion(); // OK
    l1.Number = 2;
    l1.Str = "2";

    VersionData l2 = _mock.Object.GetVersion();

    Assert.AreNotSame(l1, l2);//True as mock returns new instance
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
private static VersionData Get()
{
     return new VersionData { Number = 1, Str = "1" };
}
```

Call the above method as

```
_mock.Setup(x => x.GetVersion()).Returns(Get());

VersionData l1 = _mock.Object.GetVersion(); // OK
l1.Number = 2;
l1.Str = "2";

VersionData l2 = _mock.Object.GetVersion().Returns(Get());
```

This would give you same result in all the cases

Comment: Careful! There is a huge difference between `.Setup(x => x.GetVersion()).Returns(Get())` and `.Setup(x => x.GetVersion()).Returns(Get)`. The first one simply invokes `Get()` and hands a reference to the resulting `VersionData` instance to Moq. Then Moq keeps the reference. If the instance is later modified, there is nothing Moq can do about that. It will still return the same reference to that same instance. On the other hand, in the second one, the method group `Get` is converted into a `Func<>` delegate. Moq keeps the delegate. For each use of the method, Moq invokes the delegate again.